# ACPI errors after suspend: cannot release Mutex

Tags: acpi

I'm using a dell xps 15 with ubuntu and every time I come back after suspend I get this error:

> ACPI Error: Thread 2300... cannot release Mutex [ECMX] acquired by
> thread 2260... (2020.../emutex-370).

Should I worry? How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was a problem linked to the "Power On Lid Open" option. You need to disable it in the BIOS.